# Datagrid with column headers but no rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using WPF Data-grid with auto-generated columns. I am assigning data-table with one column but no rows as Items-source.

```
public DataTable GetInitData()
    {
        empDS = new DataSet();
        empTbl = new DataTable();
        empDS.Tables.Add(empTbl);
        dc = new DataColumn("Test");
        empDS.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);
        empDS.AcceptChanges();
        return empDS.Tables[0];
    }
```

and I call the method above in the constructor.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.grdEmp.ItemsSource = this.GetInitData().DefaultView;
    }
```

Screen-shot:

[image: Screen shot of window]

Now when I press F5 and run the  code... the Data-grid doesn't show any column. Please guide me, why it is not showing any column. If you need any other information do let me know.

Regards,
Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a single row to your table you will see the column generated. Therefore, I can only suggest this is a limitation (bug?) in the WPF `DataGrid`. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might like to add an empty row to your data first.

```
public DataTable GetInitData()
{
    var empDS = new DataSet();
    var empTbl = new DataTable();
    empDS.Tables.Add(empTbl);
    var dc = new DataColumn("Test");
    empDS.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);
    var row = empDS.Tables[0].NewRow();
    //row[0] = "foo";
    empDS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
    empDS.AcceptChanges();
    return empDS.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: Had this issue too.  Very poor that it doesn't display headers.  I need to be able to display the header and let the user enter the data.